# Parallel Data preprocessing

Tags: machine-learning, parallel, cuda

I am looking for a suggestion. Is it possible to implement the data preprocessing steps like missing value imputation, outlier detection, normalization, label encoding in parallel? Can I implement cuda/openmp/mpi programming for data preprocessing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - there are **a lot** of approaches. Depending on the language you are using / packages.

Assuming Python:

- Multiprocessing: [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html), [pool.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794433/python-using-multiprocessing-on-a-pandas-dataframe), [modin](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [pandarallel](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel), [spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html)
- GPU: [CuDF from RAPIDS](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/stable/)
- Multi-GPU: [Cudf-Dask](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/nightly/user_guide/10min.html)

If you have a Nvidia GPU - I would highly recommend the RAPIDs framework, they have plotting, machine learning, dataframes etc...

Comment: What if I am using C or C++. Please let me know.

Comment: @Encipher If I were you I'd ask a C/C++ specific question on stack overflow - perhaps with an example.